# Custom scaleout bus on SignalR causes exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I've build a custom `ScaleoutMessageBus` child class for SignalR to pass messages over my RabbitMQ bus. However, I'm getting the following exception from SignalR:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.SZArrayHelper.get_Item[T](Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.ScaleoutMessageBus.OnReceivedCore(Int32 streamIndex, UInt64 id, ScaleoutMessage scaleoutMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.ScaleoutStreamManager.OnReceived(Int32 streamIndex, UInt64 id, ScaleoutMessage message)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

What would cause this exception to occur?

Comment: I can't comment on the exception but is there any reason you aren't using the [SignalR.RabbitMQ](https://github.com/mdevilliers/SignalR.RabbitMq) library?

Comment: It requires a RabbitMQ plugin on the server, which I don't have the ability to install.

Comment: Do you have any links/blog posts to your custom scaleout. What was the goal with it and such. I am to give a talk about scaling out on Windows Azure and would love to see what you have done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to override `StreamCount` to provide for the additional stream numbers I am using.